# not getting img id from jquery loop html population

Tags: jquery

ok i have a trouble in getting an img ID. in a sense where my data is from db and i am using a function in jquery to post and retrive and loop out all the img like something this

```
function format(d) {
    var html = "";
    var card_os = null;
    $.each(d, function (k, v) {
        if (v.card_os) {
            card_os = v.card_os;
        }
        if (v.card_id) {
            var card_id = v.card_id;
            html += '<li>' +
                '<h3>' + card_id + '</h3>' +
                '<img id="card_dialog" title="' + card_id + '"     src="images/' + card_id + '.jpg" width="100" height="100"></img>' +
                '</li>';
        }
    });
    $('#ctitle').html('<h1>ChaosTCG: ' + card_os + '</h1>');
    return html;
}
```

as you can see inside my img, there is a id called card_dialog. The purpose for this ID is to get the onclick img and do a jquery dialog but with a simple code like getting the img click to do an alert is not even working

```
$("#card_dialog").on('click',function() {
    console.log("click");
    alert("click")
});
```

If I right click on my html as view source. I don't see my images populated inside the code due to is not hard coded and is with jQuery. Is this because why the #card_dialog id was not grab? if I manually code the `img` in to HTML, I was able to trigger the on click event.

Comment: For starters you create multiple items with same ID in HTML, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for dynamic elements like,

Use `your-closest-parent-static-element` to bind click event on your `img` tag, if don't know then only you can use `document`.

```
$(function(){
    $("your-closest-parent-static-element").on('click','.card_dialog',function() {
       console.log("click");
       alert(this.src);
    });
});
```

And add a class `card_dialog` to your img tag as `id must be unique` in a page like,

```
 '<img class="card_dialog" id="card_dialog" title="'+card_id+'" src="images/'+card_id+'.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>'
```

Comment: the #ctitle is just retuning a value and is working fine. Is just that i cant get the id = card_dialog to work on click not the #ctitle. The #ctitle is just another value return to append into the title of the page

Comment: @user1897151 you have multiple tags with same ID, it is the reason you can not get using ID.

Comment: changed to class, still having some problem. any better way to populate the data?

Comment: I think you are appending the html in `ul` so use the ul id in place of `your-closest-parent-static-element`

Comment: thanks for the help. Is working now after i get the closest parent static element.

Answer (score 0):

Change `id` to `class`

```
function format ( d ) {
var html = "";
var card_os = null;
$.each(d,function(k,v){
if(v.card_os){
card_os = v.card_os;
}
if(v.card_id){
 var card_id = v.card_id;
  html += '<li>'+
          '<h3>'+card_id+'</h3>'+
          '<img class="card_dialog" title="'+card_id+'"     src="images/'+card_id+'.jpg" width="100" height="100"></img>'+
          '</li>';
 }
 });
 $('#ctitle').html('<h1>ChaosTCG: '+card_os+'</h1>');
 return html;
}

$(".card_dialog").on('click',function() {
console.log("click");
alert("click")
});
```